# How to call methods in laravel

Tags: laravel, class, oop, eloquent

I have been studying Laravel now for one month or more and by brain hurts.
After making my own practice web-app this is what buggers me:

I see 2 ways (at least) to call methods / functions. Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't. Why? And what's the difference?

```
return ClubTypes::find($id);
return $this->hasMany()->...
```

And when dealing with sql, sometimes I need to put `->get()` and sometimes putting the `->get()` will give error of not defined.. what's up with that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains a lot of details that are not specific to Laravel but are PHP basics. The most significant one is the difference between instance methods called with the arrow operator `->` and static methods called with the double double-point operator `::`. Instance methods are used when the method call is relative to an instance of a class (also called object) while static methods are used for methods calls that have to do with a class but are not instance specific. An example:

```
$dog = new Dog();
$dog->bark(); // only an actual dog can bark

echo Dog::species(); // "Canis lupus familiaris" will be the same species for all dogs
```

With this information, we can now talk about the actual difference regarding Laravel methods.

#### Model Query Builder

To perform SQL queries, the model query builder can be used. It provides a convenient interface to build queries. Most of the query builder method calls can be translated to SQL very easily. The following three statements are all the same:

```
Dog::query(); // model query builder

DB::table('dogs'); // untyped query builder

FROM dogs // SQL
```

For you the most interesting is the first type of query builder, so here is a more complex example:

```
Dog::query()
    ->where('color', 'brown')
    ->where('size', '>=', 50) // centimeter
    ->get();

// in SQL
SELECT *
FROM dogs
WHERE color = 'brown' AND size >= 50
```

The method `query()` is a static method of the `Model` base class which returns a new `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object. Some people prefer calling `query()` explicitely, but you can also omit the call to it and use

```
Dog::where('color', 'brown')
    ->where('size', '>=', 50) // centimeter
    ->get();
```

instead. Here, the `Model` base class will use the magic `__callStatic()` function to tunnel the method call to `where()` to a new `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object. It basically is there just for convenience and you got it right - it's literally magic.

#### Relationships

When you define a relationship on a model, you create a function that returns something like `HasMany` or `BelongsTo`. These objects are created through convenience methods called with `$this->hasMany()` or `$this->belongsTo()`:

```
public function owner(): BelongsTo
{
    $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

When you now call this relation (which we assume to be on the `Dog` class), you have two options:

```
$owner = $dog->owner()->first();
$owner = $dog->owner()->getResults(); // the same as first()

$owner = $dog->owner;
```

The first two lines will access the relationship and perform an actual SQL query. It's basically `SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = :owner_id:`. The second line on the other hand will return the property `owner` of the dog object, which can be a relationship. If there is no `owner` property set on the object and Laravel finds a method called `owner()` (and the method returns a relationship), Laravel will load this relationship with one of the first two lines, store it under the `owner` property and return it. So it's again a magic accessor for the first (+ it stores the result). A more explicit version of both together is:

```
$dog->loadMissing('owner');
$owner = $dog->owner;
```

#### `get()` and `first()`

Relationships that return many results (such as `HasMany`) will require you to use `get()` to receive the results. Other relationships that will only return one result (such as `BelongsTo`) will require you to use `first()`. When querying models directly (like `Dog::where('color', 'brown')->get()`), you can use both, depending on what you want to get. `first()` will give you the first line of the theoretical result, which requires you to use an `orderBy()` on the query (so that the database knows which the first line is).

As soon as you retrieved a list of results with `get()`, you have an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and you cannot use query builder methods anymore. Here, the collection methods are applicable. Best you have a look at the [method reference](http://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections).

There is a pitfall, as you can use `Dog::all()` but not `Dog::query()->all()`. The `all()` method is special and can be translated to `Dog::query()->get()`.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) `ClubTypes::find()` This is know as facades. Facades provide static interface for class.Laravel have many predefine facades like, Route,Session,DB etc.

ClubType is a class
:: scope resolution operator used for calling static and constants.
find() is a static method.

2)`$this->` It is a refrence of current class and -> (arrow / object operator) is used to call the methods and properties of object.

Comment: Models like `ClubType` are not facades.